# Do I need to initialise every key of a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key

stricly speaking / best practice: do I need to set up every 'deeper nested sub array' or can you just access it?

```
//so do I need to do this:
if(!isset($multiArray[$newKey])) $multiArray[$newKey] = array();

//before I can do this?
$multiArray[$newKey][] = 'somevalue';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking no, PHP will create the new array before pushing the value to it, without any problem.

Best practice? It's probably personal opinion based, I would say create the array first for readability and it makes sense logically. If another developer picks up your code, it might not be obvious that you are creating a new array, as opposed to pushing to an existing array.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array.

Source : PHP Manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php